# Express response manipulation to send string to client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following `app.js` file for handle a specific endpoint:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    !process.env.HTTP_ACCESS_IP || res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.HTTP_ACCESS_IP);
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    );
    next();
});

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

app.post('/api/verificationstart', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: 'TEST' });
})

module.exports = app;
```

I my client side, I send HTTP REQUEST to the endpoint above, then code `res.json()`.

```
async function fetchApi() {
  return fetch('...', {
    method: 'POST',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
  });
}

async function verificationStartApi(data) {
  const res = await fetchApi();
  if (res._bodyText || res._bodyInit) {
    return res.json();
  } else {
    return res;
  }
}
```

The problem is that, from the `res.json()` I'd like to get a `string` object, not a `JSON` one. How could I do it? So that the result from `res.json()` would be `"{ message: 'TEST' }"`.

**Note that I want solution in backend. I can't touch client side.**

I've been trying anything in backend using `res.send()` but nothing did the work:

```
res.send('"{ "message": "string" }"');
res.send('{ message: "test" }');
res.send('{ "message": "test" }');
```

Comment: Can you explain what happend when you did this ? res.send('{ "message": "test" }');

Comment: @J.Doe then the result of `res.json()` is json object with one key: `message: 'test'`

Comment: just use JSON.stringify i.e JSON.stringify({ "message": "string" }); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @kg99 Still, the result of `res.json()` is JSON object. I want it to result as string.

Comment: Dont use res.json(). use res.send(JSON.stringify()); You want to send a JSON valid string. So convert it to string and send it.

Comment: @kg99 I can't change client side. If it somehow helps, this `res.json()` does result as `string` and not `JSON object` when the server side is written with `C#`, and the server uses `return Ok()` to response to client.

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Comment: so you cannot use `return res.text();` ?

Comment: @Ifaruki Guys, I though I've made it clear I with the bold text that I can't change nothing in client side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use double `JSON.stringify`.

```js
app.post('/api/verificationstart', (req, res) => {
    // it will be res.send('"{\\"message\\":\\"TEST\\"}"')
    res.send(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({ message: 'TEST' }))) 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is the ugliest answer:

```
    return res.send('"{ \\"message\\": \\"string\\" }"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Send a JSON valid string. Suppose this is your api.

```
app.post('/api/verificationstart', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify("{ message: 'TEST' }"));
})

res.send(JSON.stringify('{ "message": "test" }'));.
```

EDIT:

Get what you mean. enclose the Stringified JSON inside a string. Have a look at my update, tested it.

Comment: It's the same suggestion you had in the main comments. I told you that with this `send` the  result of `res.json()` is still JSON.

Comment: Okay, have a look at my updated answer. This way the client or server will not force it to JSON object. You dont even need Stringify. Can just quote the object within a string.

Comment: I added my own answer